# Windows 7 - Shortcut for Task Scheduler automatically connecting to another computer

Tags: windows-7, resources, scheduled-tasks

I frequently have to quickly connect to a remote PC's Task Scheduler to start/stop tasks. I would like to have a shortcut that I can just click on that will open Task Scheduler and automatically connect to the remote PC.

Comment: Is this really programming related? If not, [su] might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Yep, SuperUser was certainly a better place for this. Thanks for migrating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/w7itprogeneral/thread/7de3cec9-03a8-43b3-b3bc-27d0d13cb0e7

Here are the steps from that thread:

1. Go to Start, type MMC, right-click on mmc.exe, click Run as administrator and then click Yes if the User Account Control pops up.
2. In MMC, click File -> Add/Remove snap-ins…
3. Find Task Scheduler on the Available snap-ins list -> click Add button.
4. Choose Another computer.
5. Type the computer name or IP address.
6. Click OK.
7. Once the wizard is complete, click OK.
8. Highlight the Task Scheduler we have just created on the left pane.
9. Click File -> Save As… -> type a file name such as "Task" and save it to the Desktop.